# Need column values in one array on php+mysql.

Tags: php, mysql

**I am trying to list city names in one array on php-mysql but when I use these lines -->**

```
$sql = "select city from list"; 
$sorgu = mysql_query($sql); 
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($sorgu)) {
    print_r ($rs); 
} 
mysql_free_result($sorgu);
```

**Result is:**

```
Array ([0] => ISTANBUL) Array ([0] => LONDON) Array ([0] => PARIS) Array ([0] => OSLO)
```

**It is 4 cities and 4 arrays but I have to list them like that:**

```
Array([0] => ISTANBUL [1] => LONDON [2] => PARIS [3] => NEW YORK)
```

**What should i do?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just append the city to another array:

```
$array = array();
while ($rs = mysql_fetch_assoc($sorgu)) {
    $array[] = $rs['city'];
} 

print_r($array);
```

The code in your question will actually output:

```
Array ([city] => ISTANBUL) Array ([city] => LONDON) Array ([city] => PARIS) Array ([city] => OSLO)
```

Notice the `city` key. You would only get the output that you said if you used `mysql_fetch_row()`.

---

Side note: `mysql_*` library is deprecated, consider upgrading to PDO or MySQLi.